# Typescript iterating over object doesn't seem to work (Type Error)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying for some time now but can't get it working.

I am trying to iterate over an array in an object (the interface is imported):

```
export interface Ex {
    _id: string;
    name: string;
    tags: [
        {
            label: string,
            count: number,
            updateInfo: [
                {
                    date: string,
                    delay: number,
                }
            ],
        }
    ];
}
```

Basically I'm trying to get all tag labels into a string array.

```
getTags(): void {
    for (let tag in this.ex.tags) {
      this.tags.push(tag.label)
    }
}
```

or like this:

```
getTags(): void {
    this.ex.tags.forEach(tag => {
      this.tags.push(tag.label);
    });
  }
```

But I get the error:

> core.js:6228 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'tags' of undefined

Comment: this.tags inside for loop .. is tags was defined any where in the code explicitly.if not defined it will give you an error

Comment: yes, i definded tags like this;   'tags: string[];'

Comment: Can you share extra code snippets? How are you assigning a value to `ex` variable?

Comment: You should not use `in` when iterating over arrays unless you put a check in there. See [this answer for the definitive "how to iterate over arrays" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/215552).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined `tags` but not instantiated / or assigned to it:

Adding the property as:

```
tags = [];
```

or

```
tags = new Array<string>();
```

should resolve the issue.

Additionally, you can simplify your logic slightly:

```
this.tags = this.exTags.tags.map(x => x.label);
```

[And an example of what I see](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tqwfcv)

```
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  getTags() :Observable<Ex>{
    return new Observable(ob => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        ob.next({
            id :"a",
    name: "a name",
    tags: [
      {
      label:"a label",
      count:1,
      updateInfo: [
        {
        date: new Date().toString(),
        delay:5
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label:"b label",
      count:1,
      updateInfo: [
        {
        date: new Date().toString(),
        delay:5
        }
      ]
    }

    ] 
        })
      },1000)

    })
  }

  exTags: Ex;

  tags = new Array<string>();
  ngOnInit(){
      this.getTags().subscribe(s => { this.tags = s.tags.map(x => x.label)});
  }

}

export class Tag{
  label: string;
  count: number;
  updateInfo: [
          {
          date: string,
          delay: number
          }
    ]
}
export interface Ex {
        id: string,        
        name: string,
        tags: Tag[]
}
```

Edit

---

Since you have an OBservable, you need to wait for the get request to complete. I mocked a network async with a timeout on an async object (Stackblitz updated)

Then all you need, is to call the subscribe method on the AJAX / Observable:

```
this.getTags().subscribe(s => { this.tags = s.tags.map(x => x.label)});
```

Comment: Thank you, i actually instantiated tags[].  my problem is that ex seems to be null maybe, im new to angular and typescript sorry.. i get ex like this   `getEx(): void {  const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('_id');  this.exService.getEx(id).subscribe(ex => this.ex = ex);  }`

Comment: i think the problem might be that ex is an observable, still dont know how to fix that:D

Comment: Ah! That explains a lot! So it's a network call? In which case, yes, you have a promise unfulfilled (thus the this.ex is still null when you call to get the string array populated...)

Comment: Yes its a http get request which returns an observable of ex

Comment: @user13764911 updated it to account for async data then!